# Setting up a highly available Gitlab server

Tags: server, gitlab-ci, devops, high-availability, gitlab-omnibus

I need to setup a **highly available** Gitlab server on a **bare metal**, also i would know the best practices ( includes Security, Networking, authorizations, firewall ... etc.)   to make the job done.

Comment: Follow their instructions? https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/high-availability/

Answer (score 2):

Configuring GitLab to be highly available is a complex process. Even a minimal scaled environment consists of a minimum of 5 distinct nodes/servers. Something much closer to actual high availability can require 11 nodes. See [High Availability documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/high_availability/) for more information.

Please note that GitLab EE Omnibus also include some Premium/Ultimate-only features that make HA much easier - bundled Redis Seninel, Consul, PgBouncer, RepMgr, etc. This is in addition to access to the Support team for HA setup and configuration assistance.

Not that I'm trying to sell you on GitLab EE. But that may help to illustrate that this is a complex topic. If you truly need HA GitLab then it's probably a really critical part of your organization and that's why GitLab provides those features and services to Premium/Ultimate customers.

That said, HA GitLab *can* be achieved with GitLab CE/Core. But you will have to know how to configure each component including PostgreSQL replication, Redis/Redis Sentinel, load balancers, etc.